# opengl code to display human body graphics, reading vertices from binary file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I have a binary file which contains the vertices and normals to make a human body graphics in opengl. The graphics are made up of small  triangles. The numbers (floating points ) in the binary files are in the order,  X, Y, Z of the first vertice of a triangle followed by the normals(x,y,z) to it, Similarly two more of such set completes a triangle.( thus every 18 set of floating numbers in the binary files makes a triangle) and binary files contains several thousands of such triangles.I have written a opengl code in  windows form in c++ , to display the graphics, following is the rendering function.I am ignoring the normals and using only vertices

```
void OpenGL::RenderScene()
```

{

```
size_t file_size;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("male_16_do`enter code here`wn.bin",ios::binary|ios::in);
    if(!file){
     cout<<"Couldnt find the file"<<endl;
    }

    file.seekg(0,ios::end);
    file_size=file.tellg();
    file_size/=(sizeof(float));
    file.seekg(0,ios::beg);


std::vector<float> data(file_size);

file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]),file_size*sizeof(float)); 
for(size_t i=0;i<file_size;i++){
  //cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<data[i]<<endl;
}
vector<float>::iterator iter;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glTranslatef(1.5f,1.0f,0.0f);
for(iter=data.begin();iter!=data.end();iter++){

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP); 
int i=0;
    glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);                 
glVertex3f( data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);     
  glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);   
glVertex3f(data[i+6],data[i+7], data[i+8]);                 
  glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);                       
glVertex3f( data[i+12],data[i+13], data[i+14]);     

glEnd();
i=i+18;
}   
SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
```

}

The code appears to be right , but  on rendering  there is nothing shown in the window, can anyone suggest me what could be possibly wrong here ? Viewport is set to match the width and height of window.

Comment: first, try to get a basic triangle on the screen to understand where the problem is. 
your code seems to be using Open GL2.* syntax. You might want to shift to the 3.* way of doing things via shaders.

Comment: it works well when i tried to display a triangle with a different vertices, but doesnt work when it read the triangle verices from the data buffer, is there any mistake in translation, or viewport ?

Comment: i tried rendering with out the translation , it doesnt shows anything

Comment: What you ought to do is apply some sort of pre-processing step to find the range of values for all vertex positions in your mesh and scale those to the range [-1,1] (so they will all fit on screen in NDC). Also, draw the points as a point cloud to begin with, just in-case you are not properly generating strip-order triangles. These are all basic debugging (more like reverse engineering) tips, without more detailed information this is the best I can offer unfortunately.

Comment: the human body vertices values are all less than 1.so rescaling is not the problem i guess

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop with the `iterator` looks fishy. You're using an `iterator` over `data` as well as `i`:

Make it:

```
size_t dataLen = data.size();
for(size_t i = 0; i < dataLen; i+= 18) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_LIST); // your original code mentioned TRI_STRIP. 
    glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);                 
    glVertex3f( data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);     
    glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);   
    glVertex3f(data[i+6],data[i+7], data[i+8]);                 
    glColor3f(1,0.0f,0.0f);                       
    glVertex3f( data[i+12],data[i+13], data[i+14]); 
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work, and there is no GL_TRIANGLE_LIST defined.Anyway thanks for the suggession

Comment: @sarath: That's a D3D term, the appropriate OpenGL enum would be simply `GL_TRIANGLES`

Comment: i fixed it, problem was with the gluperspective, thanks for your sugessions.